# Arithmetic Modulo P

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Why is it that arithmetic modulo p for some prime is so useful compared to composite numbers?  Is in part because for primes any number a in $a^x \mod p$ when raised to enough $x$'s will eventually generate all numbers from $0\ldots p-1$?  Is this always true?  When do we know that something will generate all numbers smaller than the value we're modding by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainly, it's because all the non-zero numbers modulo $p$ form a multiplicative group: you will never have $ab \equiv 0 \mod p$, unless either $a \equiv 0 \mod p$ or $b \equiv 0 \mod p$. (This is in fact the *definition* of a [prime element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element) in rings.) So we can even talk of the [**field**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29) of numbers modulo $p$.

If you take the numbers modulo a composite number $n = pq$, then you get all sort of issues like two nonzero numbers getting multiplied to be $0$ modulo $n$: for example, $12 \times 15 \equiv 0 \mod 20$.

This does not mean that we don't ever work modulo a composite number; often we need to, and do. But even then, it turns out that we can just work modulo different (powers of) primes dividing the composite number $n$, and this completely defines the structure modulo $n$: this is the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

---

To answer the other parts of your question: it is *not* true that for any $a \neq 0 \mod p$, the set of numbers $a^x$ leave all possible remainders modulo $p$. For example, consider $p = 7$, and $a = 2$: the powers of $2$ mod $7$ go $2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, \dots$, so you never get the other numbers like $3$ or $5$ in there. There will however *exist* some number $a$ which generates all the nonzero numbers mod $p$, this is called a [primitive root mod p](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n).

For a composite number $n$, if we pick an $a$ for which $\gcd(a, n) = d > 1$, then any power of $a$ will always be divisible by $d$, so $a^x \mod n$ will always be one of $d, 2d, \dots$. So it will not generate all the other numbers mod $n$. However, there may exist some $a$ with $\gcd(a,n) = 1$, such that the set of numbers $a^x \mod n$ will generate all the remainders that are relatively prime to $n$. Sometimes no such $a$ may exist (e.g. consider $n = 12$).

Comment: There _exists_ an $a$ such that $a^1, \cdots, a^{p-1}$ enumerate all nonzero congruence classes modulo $p$. It is absolutely not the case that every such $a$ will do so. Similarly for the composite case.

Comment: Actually the composite case is only true for certain values of $n$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: Indeed, sorry. Have fixed it.

Comment: It seems that the Chinese Remainder Theorem works for co-prime pairs.  Are you saying that we can work modulo different primes but also modulo composite numbers?  Couldn't N = 5 x 6 x 7 be the system?  Or are you just saying that it doesn't matter because that system is just the system where N = 5 x 2 x 3 x 7 and we have 4 equations instead?

Comment: @gman: Both the things you say are true: working modulo $n = 5\times6\times7$ is the same as working mod $5,6,7$ separately, and also the same as working mod $5,2,3,7$ separately, and both these we can do because of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. So as every composite number has a unique decomposition into prime powers as $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots$ (see [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), we can, *if we want,* just work mod those prime powers. But we can also work mod $n$ itself; nothing prevents us. But it's messier.